# How to set a odbc connection in R using info from a schema

Tags: r, schema, rodbc

I am trying to set a odbc connection with a SASApp  from a schema info using RODBC library (R).

The schema is as follows:

```
schema='PMC_CENTRAL' 
USER=PMC_CENTRAL_CON
PASSWORD="XXXXXXX"
PATH=ORAPRDSTD1
```

I tried a lot of alternative codes. The most logical (for me, at least) would be:

```
library(RODBC)
con = odbcConnect("PMC_CENTRAL, uid="PMC_CENTRAL_CON", pwd="XXXXXXX")
```

I seems that I am missing the info containing in the PATH, but I don´t know how to include this.

It returns the following message:

**In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=PMC_CENTRAL;UID=PMC_CENTRAL_CON;PWD=XXXXXXX") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 01S00, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Atributo de cadeia de conexão inválido**

Thank you for any help!

Cristiano